# class based css styling for polymer's shadow dom elements

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I am trying to add styles to my shadow DOM elements using JavaScript. I am aware that you can select each element via their id by using `this.$.elementID`, but are there methods to select the element via its class properties?

Thanks

Comment: @Dilip stop suggesting jQuery everywhere...

Comment: @EugeneP. My bad. Didn't read question properly.

Comment: haha we all done that before ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to access Shadow DOM directly using,

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.classname');
```

Otherwise, as @Eugene suggested, add an identifier (`#container`) to the custom element and then use,

```
this.$.container.querySelector('.classname');
```

Additional information,
- https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding

Answer (score 3):

I would say `$.elementID` is a syntax sugar, kind of...

There is no way how to select element by class name like `$.classname` as it does not have any sense to be honest, because **classname** might not be **unique**.

have root id set in your template and then use following:

```
this.$.elementID.querySelector('.classname')
```

Comment: Eugene P's answer is also correct but Pankaj Parashar's solution  helped in solving my specific problem.